# Size incorrect in iphone 12 / 13 mini simulator

Tags: swift, swiftui

all simulator works fine and has no problem, but in iPhone 12 and 13 mini, it's not displaying correctly in view. it's always missing some part and the place the zstack over top.

and I replace the scrollview to list ,its work find but little delay. and change iPhone mini to iPhone 11 pro , it s also work find

it's this my problem or a simulator bug??

Version 13.0 (13A233)

[image]

```
ScrollView{

ZStack(alignment:.topLeading){
                    HStack{
                            Text("k")
                            .font(.footnote)
                        VStack{
                            VStack{
                                HStack{
                                    Text("Left")
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("\(exe.l, specifier: "%.0f")")
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                }
                                Slider(value: $exe.l, in: 0...slmax)
                                    .accentColor(sliderco)
                            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/1.5)
                            VStack{
                                HStack{
                                    Text("Right")
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("\(exe.2, specifier: "%.0f")")
                                        .font(.footnote)                                }
                                Slider(value: $exe.2, in: 0...slmax)
                            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/1.5)
                        }
                    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.2)
                    Button(action: {show.toggle()}, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    })
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default *Display Zoom* mode is **Standard** in the simulator, you can change it and see the difference. So, there are two modes: **Standard** and **Zoomed**

To change it go to **Settings → Developer → View**